# Rational Coordinates with two intersecting lines

Tags: geometry, rational-numbers

If there are two 2D lines with rational slopes that intersect, must the intersection point have rational co-ordinates?

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this and not sure how you prove it?

Comment: Just build explicit formula for intersection point.

Answer (score 1):

Let the first line have equation $y = \frac{p}{q}x + c_1$, and the second line have equation $\frac{r}{s}x + c_2$. Then, the intersection point is given by $\frac{p}{q}x + c_1 = \frac{r}{s}x + c_2$, and then:

$$(ps)x + (qs)c_1 = (rq)x + (qs)c_2$$
$$\Rightarrow (ps-rq)x=(qs)(c_2-c_1)$$
$$\Rightarrow x = \frac{(qs)(c_2-c_1)}{ps-rq}$$

$p,q,r,s$ must be rational, but $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be irrational. 
Therefore, $x$ is not always rational. One such example are the lines $x - \sqrt{2}$ and $2x + \sqrt{2}$. Here $x = -2\sqrt{2}$, which is irrational.